# Center image but left align its caption

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to center an image in CSS and left-align its caption below so the text remains the same width as the image even when it consists of multiple lines and always stays aligned to the left edge of the image?

Desired Result:
[image: image with left aligned caption below]

It seemed to me like this must be very easy but indeed I could not find a solution **without specifying a width to the container**.

Here the simplest setup I could think of but it breaks with multi-line-caption.

```css
.image-wrapper{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Image">
    <div class="caption">Your Caption Text Here But What If It Spans Multiple Lines</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On your image-wrapper class remove the display table then you have a class for the paragraph. 

.caption {
 max-width: same as your image width; width:100%; margin:0 auto;text-align:left;
}

Comment: ```.image-wrapper{display: grid;
 place-content: center;
 grid-template-columns: min-content;
 gap: 1ex 0;
}```